# Java toObject() for Strings that are printed from toString()

Tags: java

The component I'm working on is changing its datastore from mongo -> mysql. In mongo, you can fit a pojo (with other pojo fields) into a document, not in mysql.

For a particular Object, I'd like to be able to `toString()` it and store that in a mysql `TEXT` column.

When I retrieve it, I'd like to be able to `MyClass.staticToObject(String stringifiedObj)` to get a `MyClass` instance. Is this possible?

I know I can write a custom `toString()` and parser but it seems a little tedious/prone to errors.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Yeah, serialize it .

Comment: Are you sure you want to store it in a `TEXT` column? That would be still thinking in Mongo style, but you're not working with Mongo anymore.

Comment: @Kayaman, all fields have been extract to their own columns, except this one which has 'sub-documents'. I'm battling time too and this solution seems right. Serialization could work thanks had not thought of that Dave Newton

Answer (score 1):

Use any JSON library Guava, Jackson f.i. Serialize it to JSON -> store to DB -> retrieve -> deserialize. I think it's pretty common use case for NOSQL DBs. And for you needs you could add 2 static methods to pojo toJson/fromJson.